# How to distinguishing right and left button in SpanSelector?

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget, mouse, interactive

I want to use `SpanSelector` to select two intervals in a plot. To save the different extrema of the intervals, I would like to use a flag depending on if I selected the interval using the right or the left button (so I can distinguish the two wanted intervals).

Is the above possible?

---

Edited:

To be more specific: I would like that once displayed the plot, the `SpanSelector` draws a red span of area if done by the left button and a blue span of area if done by the right button.

---

Example:

The code below lets the user interactively select an interval and then prints such interval

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.widgets as mwidgets  

fig = plt.figure() 
ax = plt.axes() 
x = np.arange(0,2*np.pi)  
y = np.sin(x) 
ax.plot(x,y) 

def onselect(vmin, vmax):
    print(vmin, vmax)

span = mwidgets.SpanSelector(ax, onselect, 'horizontal') 

plt.show()
```

I would like to modify the code above such that if the interval is drawn by the left button, then it prints `"LEFT: vimin, vmax"` and, that if the interval is drawn by the right button, then it prints `"RIGHT: vmin, vmax"`.

Is the above possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SpanSelector(..., button=1)
```

would be the span selector for the left mousebutton and

```
SpanSelector(..., button=3)
```

would be the span selector for the right mousebutton.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. This helped but still, I did not quite get what I want to. I edited my question above to be more precise.

Comment: This answer suggests to use *two* SpanSelectors.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using `mpl_connect`. I did not make the distinction between left and right click but I made the code treat the `SpanSelector` input in a different way depending on if the mouse-selected span was preceded by an `enter` keystroke or a `shift+enter` keystroke. I leave the code below in case it is useful to someone else.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.widgets as mwidgets  

fig = plt.figure() 
ax = plt.axes() 
x = np.arange(0,2*np.pi)  
y = np.sin(x) 
ax.plot(x,y) 
ax.set_title('[Press \'enter\' and \'shift+enter\' to select the intervals]')

def onselect(vmin, vmax):
    if plot_key_input == 'enter':
        print('Interval type 1:', vmin, vmax)
    if plot_key_input == 'enter+shift':
        print('Interval type 2:', vmin, vmax)

# The variable plot_key_input will store the key that is pressed during the plot visualization
plot_key_input = None
# Get the key pressed during the plot visualization
def onPressKey(event):
# Defined as a global variable so it will affect other programs and functions
    global plot_key_input
    plot_key_input = event.key

# Connect the keys to the function onPressKey during the plot visualization
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', onPressKey)

span = mwidgets.SpanSelector(ax, onselect, 'horizontal') 

plt.show() 

# Disconnect the keys to the function onPressKey
fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
```